# Having Trouble Deleting a Value from a Collect_Select box in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a Delete Button/Link on my `views/admin_lookups/index.html.erb` page.

I am able to create a new value and save it to my `category list` and `category collection_select box`.

Can't get delete to work though. I've gotten everything from routing errors to template errors.

Application contains an `admin_lookup model` and a `category model`

Here is my code thus far:

**views/admin_lookups/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @admin_lookup do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:category_id, :class => "control-label") %> 
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
  </div>
    </div>
 <% end %>

<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
  <ul id="category">
    <%= category.name %>
  </ul>   
<% end %>

<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name, "New Name" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit %>

 **Here is where I am trying to implement my delete link** 
<%= link_to 'Delete', @category, remote: true, method: :delete %> 

<% end %>
```

**admin_lookups_controller.rb**

```
class AdminLookupsController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @admin_lookups = AdminLookup.all
    @admin_lookup = AdminLookup.new
    @category = Category.new
    @categories = Category.all
  # @category = Category.destroy
    ....
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    @category.save
    render nothing: true
  end
  def index 
    @categories = Category.all
    render nothing: true
  end
  def destroy 
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

**Views/admin_lookups/destroy.js.erb**

```
 $("select option[value=<%= @category.id %>]").remove()
```

Comment: Is `@category = destroy` a typo? Please change it to `@category.destroy` if it isn't and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry. It is supposed to be @category.destroy

Comment: Did you try to remove the `render nothing: true` from the destroy action and rename `views/admin_lookups/destroy.js.erb` to `Views/categories/destroy.js.erb`?

Comment: @AhmadSherif just tried that....still getting my routing error. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/categories"):`    However when I run a `rake routes` I do have `DELETE /categories/:id(.:format) categories#destroy`  Do I need call `@category = Category.destroy` in my `admin_lookups_controller.rb/index` ?  It's commented out right now because it gave me an argument error.

Comment: Just spotted another mistake, please replace `link_to 'Delete', @category` with `link_to 'Delete', category` (drop the @ before category) and try again (same suggestions in my last comment).

Comment: just tried it....`NameError  undefined local variable or method 'category'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61585/discussion-between-ahmad-sherif-and-twdeveloper).

Comment: Sounds good. I just replied.

Comment: @Ahmad Sherif was able to walk me through my code to achieve the results I was looking for. Below is the updated code that answered my question. Hope this is able to help someone out in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated code:

**views/admin_lookups/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :category, method: :delete, :url => categories_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:category_id, :class => "control-label") %> 
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.collection_select(:id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
  </div>
    </div>
 <%= f.submit "Delete Category Value" %> 
 <% end %>

<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
  <ul id="category">
    <%= category.name %>
  </ul>   
<% end %>

<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name, "New Name" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :categories do
  collection do 
    delete :index, to: 'categories#destroy'
  end
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    @category.save
    render nothing: true
  end
  def index 
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
       format.js {}
    end
  end
  def destroy 
    @category = if params[:id].present?
      Category.find(params[:id])
    elsif params[:category].present?
      Category.find(params[:category][:id])
    end
    @category.destroy
  end 
end
```

**Views/categories/destroy.js.erb**

```
 $("select option[value=<%= @category.id %>]").remove()
```